# Can we use Diffie-Hellman public key encrytion algorithm with asp.net login control?

Tags: asp.net, login-control, diffie-hellman

I am trying to find out the internals of login control in asp.net.
Does it uses some Public key encryption algorithm to exchange a key and then uses it for further communication as a symmetric key.

Also do we have our say in choosing the encryption algorithms like for ex i want to specifically use Diffie Hellman with login control. Is it possible and how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm no cryptographer...

- The Login controls use ASP.Net Membership along with Forms Authentication [by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx).
- You can [create your own auth mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx#the_login_control)
- The default hash algorithm used in ASP.net Membership is [SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx). Yes, you have a choice. I've had to use MD5 in a migration project (if memory serves from phpBB to ASP.net) more than a few years back...
- (see disclaimer) Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDiffieHellman) info

  - In [config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig.aspx)
  - [ECDiffieHellman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.aspx)

hth...